# jquery replace string where complete string matches

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have a string.

```
var myexample="'product1','product61','product27','product15'";
```

I want to then replace `product1` with `blank`

so I say:
myexample=myexample.replace(product1, "");

This works, the problem is that is replaces product1 and the product 1 in product15 so my result is:

```
"'','product61','product27','5'";
```

I think what I need to do is get the length of the foun object to replace, if it is the same length as my search string then replace else ignore.

any advice welcome as always.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
myexample = myexample.replace("'product1'", "''");
```

Output:

```
"'','product61','product27','product15'"
```